# import and use remark & rehype plugins in Observable

Tags: observablehq

### Import Stubborn Modules in Observable

With the [introduction of require](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/require), [observable](https://observablehq.com) has enabled us to use thousands of open-source JavaScript modules in notebooks. This has worked fine couple of years back. But few notebooks are starting to return error now.

I'm looking for a way to use `remark` & `rehype` plugins in observable. This is an [example notebook](https://observablehq.com/@grantcuster/markdown-to-grid) that I would like to be able to run successfully. In this notebook, I noticed that the error was while requiring the module, so I tried updating it to the latest version (using [require-debugger](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/module-require-debugger)), but it returns an empty object (screenshot below). So the related cells return `not a function` error

Does newer versions of Observable have limited support for require? If not how to get this to work?

[image: Updated version to require]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution for this particular module might be to load it like this:

> remark = import("https://cdn.skypack.dev/remark@14.0.1?min").then(d => d.remark)

Note that this issue is not specific to Observable, but happens upstream (on bundle.run). I tried to build the older version with a locally-hosted packd (the software that powers bundle.run), and I get the same error as the one that shows on bundle.run.

Comment: another useful resource for importing stubborn modules in observable: https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/how-to-require-stubborn-modules